# How to extend the range of Dynamic Array formulas in excel (without using tables)

Tags: excel, excel-formula, dynamic-arrays

In the below example, I have two dynamic array formulas in cell C2 and D2

```
C2 = "=VLOOKUP(A2:A7,$Q$2:$R$9,2,FALSE)"  
D2 = "=SUBSTITUTE(B2:B7,"Dep ","")*1"
```

These formula ranges from A2 till A7 and B2 till B7.
I want the range A7 to increase or decrease based on the range of the data.  Like if there is data till A10 the formula should extend till A10 and B10.

Converting this to table is not an option.  And the data would be copied and pasted by the user in that range.

Can you suggest a way to achieve this without VBA.

[image]

Comment: Are the values in A always numbers?

Answer (score 1):

You can use MATCH to return the cell in A that has the last number:

```
MATCH(1E+99,A:A)
```

Note: This assumes column A uses numbers only in the data and that there are no numbers below the table in question.

Then using that in the formula with INDEX we can return the last cell of the column:

```
INDEX(A:A,MATCH(1E+99,A:A))
```

And

```
INDEX(B:B,MATCH(1E+99,A:A))
```

Then combine that with your formula:

```
=VLOOKUP(A2:INDEX(A:A,MATCH(1E+99,A:A)),$Q$2:$R$9,2,FALSE)
```

```
=SUBSTITUTE(B2:INDEX(B:B,MATCH(1E+99,A:A)),"Dep ","")*1
```

Now the range reference is also dynamic and will grow or shrink depending on data.